# Regular Perturbation Series and Fisher's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, dynamical-systems

In my [textbook](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=PmXsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=asymptotic%20solution%20and%20stability%20of%20wavefront%20solutions%20to%20the%20fisher%20equation&source=bl&ots=KoK8g7MNc9&sig=YWj1P4G65AKHw4BcIw8hB3P1SB8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi85NC12erPAhWL14MKHUzCALYQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=asymptotic%20solution%20and%20stability%20of%20wavefront%20solutions%20to%20the%20fisher%20equation&f=false) (end of page 282) it goes over the  calculation of the Asymptotic Solution and Stability of Wavefront Solutions of the Fisher Equation.

In this it transforms the Fisher equation $$U''+cU'+U(1-U)=0$$ into the equation $$\epsilon\frac{d^2g}{d\xi^2}+\frac{dg}{d\xi}+g(1-g)=0 \;\;\;\;\oplus$$ with the boundary conditions $$g(-\infty)=1, \;g(\infty)=0, \;0<\epsilon\leq \frac{1}{c^2},\; g(0)=1/2$$

The text then states to look for solutions of the above equation as a regular perturbation series (a standard power series) in $\epsilon$, that is let

$$g(\xi;\epsilon)=g_0(\xi)+ \epsilon g_1(\xi)+...$$

With the conditions

$$U(0)=1/2 \Rightarrow g(0;\epsilon)=1/2, \;\;\forall\epsilon$$
$$g_0(-\infty)=1, \;g_0(\infty)=0, \;g_0(0)=1/2,$$
$$g_i(\pm\infty)=0, \;g_i(0)=0, \;\;i=1,2,3... $$

The textbook then states that it takes the regular perturbation series and substitutes it into equation $\oplus$, then equating powers of $\epsilon$ gets

$$O(1):\frac{dg_0}{d\xi}=-g_0(1-g_0) \Rightarrow g_0(\xi)=(1+e^\xi)^{-1}$$
$$O(\epsilon):\frac{dg_1}{d\xi}+(1-2g_0)g_1=-\frac{d^2g_0}{d\xi^2}$$

My problem is I don't understand how they got to the last part. Can someone show me what happens when I substitute my power series into $\oplus$ and how they took $O(1)$ and calculated $g_0(\xi)$? (I will provide more information if needed)

Comment: Why not to take this power series and plug it in?

Comment: Well that's my problem right now. Like I'm having a mental blank on how to plug it in... It's such a stupid thing...

Comment: I've been more confused about the integration of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, take $g=g_0+\epsilon g_1+\ldots$ and plug it in:
$$
\epsilon(g_0+\epsilon g_1+\ldots)''+(g_0+\epsilon g_1+\ldots)'+(g_0+\epsilon g_1+\ldots)(1-g_0-\epsilon g_1-\ldots)=0.
$$
The derivatives are linear so we get
$$
\epsilon g_0''+\epsilon^2 g_1''+\ldots+g_0'+\epsilon g_1'+\ldots+(g_0+\epsilon g_1+\ldots)(1-g_0-\epsilon g_1-\ldots)=0.
$$
Now collect all the terms on the left without $\epsilon$:
$$
g_0'+g_0(1-g_0)=0,
$$
you get the first equation. Collect all the terms with $\epsilon$ and so on...